# Signature based NIDS regex matching

Tags: regex, regular-language, intrusion-detection

I am trying to build a signature based intrusion detection system but when matching regex against payloads, I encountered an expression beginning with a caret `^` which means match at the beginning of a line in regular expression.

What I wanted to be sure of is should this be at the beginning of the entire payload or simply anywhere in the payload after a newline `\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `^` stands for **the beginning of the string**.

So assuming you're treating your whole payload (newline included) as a single string, `^` will mean at the beginning of the payload.

If you want to change this behavior you need to turn on the multiline flag `m` by adding `(?m)` at the beginning of your regex (depending on the language you're using, there might be other ways of doing so).

This flag will make `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of a *line*, the beginning and end of the *string* becoming available with `\A` and `\Z`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am actually writing my own parser to match regular expressions so i needed to make sure I am doing it right.